# Invalid syntax for INSERT INTO MySQL query from Python

Tags: python, mysql-python

When trying to execute the following:

```
def postToMySQL(date,data,date_column_name,data_column_name,table):

cursor = conn.cursor ()


sql = "\"\"\"INSERT INTO " + table + " (" + date_column_name + ", " + data_column_name + ") VALUES(%s, %s)" + "\"\"\"" #+ ", " + "(" + date + ", " + data + ")"  
cursor.execute(sql,(date,data))
```

I get this error:

> _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax... near:
>   **\'**"""INSERT INTO natgas (Date, UK) VALUES(\'2012-05-01 13:00:34\', \'59.900\')"""**\'** at line 1')

I'm puzzled as to where the syntax is wrong, because the following hardcoded example works fine:

```
def postUKnatgastoMySQL(date, UKnatgas):

cursor = conn.cursor ()

cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO natgas (Date, UK)VALUES(%s, %s)""", (date, UKnatgas))
```

Can you spot the error?

Alternately, could you tell me how to pass parameters to the field list as well as the value list?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those triple quotes are a way of representing a string in python. They aren't supposed to be part of the actual query.

On another note, be very sure you trust your input with this approach. Look up `SQL Injection`.

Comment: Ah, brilliant! The following now works: sql = "INSERT INTO " + table + " (" + date_column_name + ", " + data_column_name + ") VALUES(%s, %s)" I've heard a bit about SQL injection. I have nothing of value (yet) but is there an easy alternative to this approach?

Answer (score 0):

> \'"""INSERT INTO natgas (Date, UK) VALUES(\'2012-05-01 13:00:34\',
>   \'59.900\')"""\' at line 1')

this is obviously not a vlaid SQL command. You need to get the backslashes out of there, you are probably escaping stuff you shouldn't.

the triple quotes for example sure are unnecessary there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Weasel. I'm trying to replicate this as a string >"""INSERT INTO natgas (Date, UK)VALUES(%s, %s)"""< and then pass it to cursor.execute. In order to do so, I have to escape the three """  or else python thinks I'm closing the string off.

Comment: the triple quotes should not be part of the query, they are python syntax. also it seems you escaped the single quotes in the values. try removing all the backslashes...

Comment: Unfortunately when I remove the slashes I just get a block quote: """"INSERT INTO " + table + " (" + date_column_name + ", " + data_column_name + ") VALUES(%s, %s)" + """ and python does not recognise that there are variables in the string.

Comment: Thanks Weasel, got it working. The triple quotes were indeed unnecessary.